# Convert a QVariant to a char*

Tags: c++, qt

I have a variable of type QVariant in Qt5:

`my_var = QVariant(QString, "(198.95875549316406, 124.93024444580078, 38.149349212646484)")`

How can I get a `char*` with the coordinates?

Like

```
char * my_char = "(198.95875549316406, 124.93024444580078, 38.149349212646484)";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example like this:

```
QVariant my_var(QString(
  "(198.95875549316406, 124.93024444580078, 38.149349212646484)"));
qDebug() << my_var.toString();
auto std_str = my_var.toString().toStdString();
const char* ptr = std_str.c_str();
std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
```

Just don't do it in one line like `my_var.toString().toStdString().c_str()` because temporary `std::string` created by `toStdString` will be immediately destroyed and your raw `const char*` pointer invalidated.

Comment: However, it is safe to use the `c_str` pointer in the same expression that retrieves it, eg: `std::cout << my_var.toString().toStdString().c_str() << std::endl;` is perfectly fine. But yes, if you need to store the pointer in a variable, then store the backing `string` to a variable as well.

Comment: For specific encodings, going via QByteArray might be also useful: e.g. `const auto ba = my_var.toUtf8(); const char* ptr = ba.constData(); …`